# Kotlin : How to use Branch sdk to share an image?

Tags: android, kotlin, branch.io

In my android app with kotlin language with IDE Android studio 4.0,
I want to share a product which have an image and some other information.
I use the Branch Sdk, I added a new module in my project.
In AndroidManifest.xml, I add the following instructions :

```
   <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="......" />
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="...app.link" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                        android:host="...-app.link"
                        android:scheme="https" />
                <!-- example-alternate domain is required for App Links when the Journeys/Web SDK and Deepviews are used inside your website.  -->
                <data
                        android:host="....test-app.link"
                        android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

In my build.gradle, I added :

```
implementation project(path: ':Branch-SDK')
```

Let's move to kotlin code now, I add the following function :

```
fun prepareSharingLink(
    itemID: String,
    itemType: String,
    imageURL: String?,
    customTitle: String = ""
): BranchUniversalObject {

    val canonical = itemType.plus("/").plus(itemID)
    var branchUniversalObject = BranchUniversalObject()
    branchUniversalObject.canonicalIdentifier = canonical
    branchUniversalObject.title = customTitle
    branchUniversalObject.setContentDescription("")
    branchUniversalObject.setContentImageUrl(imageURL!!)
    branchUniversalObject.contentMetadata.customMetadata["itemType"] = itemType
    branchUniversalObject.contentMetadata.customMetadata["itemID"] = itemID
    branchUniversalObject.isLocallyIndexable
    branchUniversalObject.isPublicallyIndexable
    branchUniversalObject.setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PRIVATE)
    return branchUniversalObject
}
```

And In the product activity, when I click on share button, I add the following code :

```
share.setOnClickListener {
            val image = productData.mainImage
            val url = this.getString(R.string.image_URL) + image
            buo = Utility(this).prepareSharingLink(
                productData.id.toString(),
                "product",
                url,
                UtilityTools.getInstance().getValue(productData.name)
            )
            val linkProperties = LinkProperties()
            val message =
                if (UtilityTools.getIsAr()) "يرجى الاطلاع على هذا المنتج "
                else "Check out this product"


            val ss = ShareSheetStyle(this, "Check this out!", message)
                .setCopyUrlStyle(
                    resources.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send),
                    "Copy",
                    "Added to clipboard"
                )
                .setMoreOptionStyle(
                    resources.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search),
                    "Show more"
                )
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.FACEBOOK)
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.EMAIL)
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.MESSAGE)
                .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.HANGOUT)
                .setAsFullWidthStyle(true)
                .setSharingTitle("Share With")

      buo.showShareSheet(this, linkProperties, ss, object : Branch.BranchLinkShareListener {
                override fun onShareLinkDialogLaunched() {}
                override fun onShareLinkDialogDismissed() {}
                override fun onLinkShareResponse(sharedLink: String?, sharedChannel: String?, error: BranchError?) {
                    Log.e("LinkShared", "success")
                }
                override fun onChannelSelected(channelName: String) {}
            })
```

After all this, I couldn't sharing the product detail yet,
So, How can I use Branch sdk to share this product ? And where's the problem in my code ?

Comment: Do you mean to say that nothing happens on clicking on Share button or are you unable to read the shared link data?

Comment: yes,nothing happens on clicking on Share button but I got the Url